# Animation - Revelation of a text by a shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I've been learning how to code for some time and I come to you because I'm stuck on the construction of an animation. I've been trying to figure out how to make it for two days (image attached) but it seems that I don't have the knowledge to build this animation alone. I've been looking in css but the revelation of a text at a fixed position is not possible with a moving element, and I don't master java script frameworks.

The animation starts with the right image (this is the default state), it then goes through the left image to then let appear only the orange background and the texts.
[Animation description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk5wU.jpg)

What I can't manage to do is the progressive revelation of the text by this orange form (the two little bars are important and I want to keep them even if it's more complicated).

I simply don't know what to search on google to find the answer, nor if I should do it with css or js or a framework.
I don't necessarily want you to give me the code already pre-made but mostly a direction to exploit.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You are probably going to need both CSS and JS to do that animation, plus perhaps SVG. You don't need any frameworks. I'd start by looking into clipping and masking.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll might want to make an SVG shape, and then use `clip-path` to create a mask. These two articles work their way up to something like what you’re after:

- https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/
- https://css-tricks.com/animating-with-clip-path/

The SVG itself could be animated, or you might animate the `clip-path` property which is covered more in that second link.

Hope that’s helpful!